# Add additional columns to SSIS output depending on value of a parameter

Tags: ssis

I need to add additional columns to a CSV depending on the value of a parameter in SSIS.

My current control flow looks like this:
[image: Control Flow]

And my current data flow looks like this:

[image]

In short, I work out which contracts I need to run it for, then pass that to a parameter. I then loop through the list of contracts and output a CSV from a SQL query run against the contract parameter.  The same columns are required for each contract from my SQL query, just the values need to be filtered to the contract specific data.

One specific contract in my list needs a few additional columns adding to the start of each CSV as part of their ETL process.  These columns will contain the same data down each row of the CSV.

I don't want to make a new package just for them, as this will increase the ongoing maintenance (I like to only have to change things once if a change applies to all contracts).

I'm not sure how to make the additional columns appear just for one contract and not the others.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot change the columns in a dataflow at run time.   They can only be set at package creation time.

You don't have to make a new package for the odd contract, but you do have to make a new dataflow for it.

Make a dataflow for that contract and in your foreach loop use a dummy script task as a starting point and use precedence constraints to go to the correct data flow for that contract.